# Using TypeLite to generate C# classes with DataMember name

Tags: c#, typescript, serialization, typelite

I'm currently using [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/) to build .d.ts interface files from a set of C# classes. I've run into an issue where some of the classes have attributes for DataMember where the given value is different from the property name. In this case, I'd like for TypeLite to use the DataMember attribute rather than the property name - unfortunately, I can't find anywhere in the documentation that says this is possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is the `[TsProperty(Name="")]` attribute, is that an option?

Comment: Not really - too big a change across the existing files. Although it would maintain backward compatibility. It might be OK, but not the preferred option. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [code](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/src/076249af9d12d08315cab8b4f1531716d46c78e4/TypeLite/TsModels/TsProperty.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) only checks for the built-in `[TsProperty]` attribute to rename properties:

```
var attribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<TsPropertyAttribute>(false);
if (attribute != null) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Name)) {
        this.Name = attribute.Name;
    }

    this.IsOptional = attribute.IsOptional;
}
```

You could trivially patch this to also include the `[DataMember]` attribute:

```
var dataMemberAttribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute>(false);
if (dataMemberAttribute!= null) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataMemberAttribute.Name)) {
        this.Name = dataMemberAttribute.Name;
    }

    this.IsOptional = !dataMemberAttribute.IsRequired;
}
```

Perhaps you could submit a pull request with that fix. Make sure to add tests and consider the case where both attributes are applied to a property.

For consistency you'd also have to patch in support for the `[DataContract]` attribute to be able to rename classes.

Comment: This sounds pretty spot-on for our needs. I'll give this a go and be sure to come back and mark the fix if this does the trick. Thanks :)